# Why does onload function run before src is declared?

Tags: javascript, html, events

Here's my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      *{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
      canvas{ display: block; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px solid #000;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id = "game"> 
    </canvas>
    <script>
      var y = new Image();
      y.onload = alerting();
      function alerting() {
        alert("yeaaa");
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      //y.src = "Untitled.bmp";
      ctx.drawImage(y, 5, 5);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Two questions:

- Why does the .onload run before image source is declared?  I thought it should run after the .src is declared.
- Why can I rename `onload` to anything and it will still run?

`

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the .onload run before image source is declared? I thought it should run after the .src is declared.

Because with parentheses in place you're calling the `alerting` function immediately, instead of just assigning it like this:

```
y.onload = alerting;
```

> Why can I rename onload to anything and it will still run?

The same reason: `alerting()` is not a function - it's the result of calling it. So whichever property of `y` it's assigned to, the expression is still calculated.

The bottom line: functions are first class citizens in JavaScript - they are values, they are objects etc. So treat them like that, and you should be fine. )

Answer (score 3):

It runs because you're telling it to:

```
y.onload = alerting();
                   ^-- call the function immediately
```

v.s.

```
y.onload = alerting;
                   ^--- assign the function object itself, not its results.
```

Comment: E.g., `y.onload = alerting()` **calls** `alerting` and assigns its return value to `y.onload` exactly the way `x = foo()` **calls** `foo` and assigns its return value to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the parenthesis after `alerting`, you are calling that function, then doing the assignment. You should just assign the function by reference and not the return value of the function to your `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

It runs first because you call it here

```
y.onload = alerting();
```

the onload event handler expects a callback function which should just be the handle

```
y.onload = alerting;
```

Furthermore, nothing happens in your original version's onload handler as a result of alerting returning undefined (it has no return value). This is essentially what happened:

```
alerting();
y.onload = undefined;
```